# Windows 7 - store network password

Tags: windows-7, password, webdav

Windows 7 keeps asking for a password every time I mount a webdav.

I don't want to store a password in a .bat file because it's so insecure.

Is there any way to force system store it? Manually adding credentials in user manager helps storing passwords for SMB shares but for webdav doesn't.

btw, as far as I remember, Vista had the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using basic authentication, then unfortunately, Windows 7 doesn't allow this

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2673544

> In Windows 7 Basic authentication cannot be persisted by the Credential Manager in Windows 7, this is new to the OS. The only way
>   with Basic authentication mode to reconnect is to disconnect the drive
>   and reconnect again, because WinHttp is not able to retrieve saved
>   Basic and Digest credentials. For persistent connections ensure that
>   an authentication scheme is selected that allowes to have persistent
>   credentials through a reboot. For example Kerberos for authentication
>   or certificate based authentication will work.

If you are using integrated windows auth, then there is a reg setting you need to enable to allow it to work.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941050

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters
AuthForwardServerList (MULTI_SZ)
```

Add the name of the Server there

Answer (score 0):

Adding the address of the WebDAV host to your Internet 'Trusted Sites' zone may work around this issue.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't